# Reading / displaying multiple Sharepoint 2010 lists

Tags: 2010, list, search

We have an established Sp2010 site and each team within the company has their own section on it with lists of whose within their teams. Each list is names Team Members List and an example team page is:

```
https://spweb.dcp.co.uk/sites/dcp/teams/ChargeableTeam/

https://spweb.dcp.co.uk/sites/dcp/teams/LifeTeam/
```

etc.

In total there are about 50 teams with over 500 members of staff.

I want to create a search function that allows people to search for an employee and find their extension, username etc. - this is all contained within the Team members list.

So I need to find a way to pull all the info from all the team member lists across the varying pages into one place for the search function. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

I should mention I'm not able to add or create an special web parts and I don't have access to the direct farm - our IT is outsourced and they restrict our access. I'm fairly new so may need some help applying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a business reason why you are using lists for this rather than augmenting the User Profile to include a Team Membership property? If you do that the People Search page will work for this purpose perfectly.

Comment: i DON'T THINK SO BUT ITS A PRE BUILT SYSTEM AND i DONT HAVE ACCESS TO TEHF ARM ITSELF - VERY LIMITED TO WHAT i CAN ADD/ DO. i'VE DONE SEARCH FUNCTIONS BEFORE BUT NEED STO PULL ALL OF THE LSITS TOGETHER IN ONE PALCE FOR MY SEACH TO WORK.

Comment: @Daniel, computer stuck in caps-lock? :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `SPSiteDataQuery` for querying and combining list results from various lists or sites.

[SharePoint 2010 SPSiteDataQuery with Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example)

Comment: Looks good but I dont have the grid web part - it doesnt explain how I would apply this either !

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 I would create a Search Scope that includes Contacts from all of the target lists. Then I would create a search page that is restricted to that Scope. Edit the XSL to include the contact columns and present a good looking display. Edit the refiners to enable the users to filter on the resulting fields.